# Ending application

Tags: android

I've overwritten onPause, onDestroy and onStop to contain the following:

```
finalize();
super.on...();
```

I've overwritten finalize to contain the following:

```
setHighScores();
nView.release();
try {
    super.finalize();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the application keeps on running when closing it (home-button, back-button, red-tele-button).

Yes, I am sure I want to end it. Don't try swaying me into this mobile-multitasking. It's unnecesary for games.

***TLDR: How do you forcefully close an android app?***

Comment: I try it anyway. Example: onPause() is called when I take a call while the game is running. Usually continiue playing after the call. If your game does extensive loading/unloading of resources, that behaviour would drain my battery and waste my time. Do you really think that improves your app? Try this with angry birds and imagine you have the whole loading screen after each call or after you checked this nice easter egg in the browser for a second. Conclusion: I would not buy your game.

Comment: If android apply that task policy is for something. It isn't necesary kill your app and it isn't a good improvement for your app do that.

Comment: How are you identifying that your game is running? If you are still in some game thread executing code, then that's your code's problem. If you are looking at the "Running" list in Application settings and it doesn't say cached background process, then it's your codes problem too.

Comment: The reason why you have no business terminating your app is Android will do it for you when resources get low. Your paused app idling in the background is not consuming any needed resources (after all, you _are_ stopping your unneeded threads, aren't you)? If the user returns to your app then everything is prepped... if you finish() then you screw your user with no benefit to them. Do you really want to be an app your users uninstall over silliness on your part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is call the activity's `Finish` method:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)